# Оптимизация алгоритма решения для задачи

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Никак не могу справиться с задачей, заданной в ВУЗе - пишет, что превышен лимит памяти. Я вообще не понимаю как тут её решить иначе. Вот сама задача:

[image: Экранный снимок текста задачи]

А вот код моей попытки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<string>A;
   while (1)
   {
      string m;
      cin>>m;
      if (m[0]=='#')
         break;
      A.push_back(m);
   }
   while (A.size()!=1)
   {
      for (int i=0;i<A.size()-1;i++)
      {
         for (int j=i+1;j<A.size();j++)
         {
            if (A[i]==A[j])
            {
               A.erase(A.begin()+j);
               A.erase(A.begin()+i);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   cout<<A[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: сайтик вконтакта не видно в многих частях мира. И Вашу картинку также. Но похоже, Вы просто пытаетесь удалить дубликаты.

Comment: Да, сначала ввожу всё в вектор строк, а затем просто удаляю повторяющиеся, то объем памяти выделенный под данную задачу не позволяет мне это провернуть

Comment: Про операцию xor что-нибудь знаете?

Comment: Хм, да, конечно

Comment: @KoVadim, скопировал экранный снимок на Imgur.

Comment: нужен xor. В этом случае задача решается в один проход.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить как тут использовать xor?

Comment: @zzron228 Объяснил в ответе.

Comment: Аа, не заметил, спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Операция xor имеет такое свойство: `a ^ a = 0` и `a ^ b ^ a = b` (в любом порядке). Это применяется, например, при рисовании пером в xor-режиме - повторное рисование в тех же координатах стирает предыдущее, фон остаётся неизменным. Этот же принцип применим и здесь

Заводим строку A длиной 255, заполняем нулями.
Читаем очередную строку, ксорим все символы с соответствующими символами A.
Повторяем до конца файла.

То, что осталось в результате в A - искомая непарная строка.

Затраты памяти - только на две строки. Время обработки - минимально возможное.

Comment: Алгоритм достаточно интересный, вряд ли бы додумался до него. Написал программу на нем и она работает, но, увы, на сайте мне снова при попытке отправки выдало что на первом тесте превышение лимита памяти, тут, наверное, нужно работать напрямую с файлом

Comment: Не надо читать весь файл в вектор, строки обрабатывать сразу же

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string> s;
    string m, u;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> m;
        if (m == "#")
            break;
        if (s.find(m) == s.end())
        {
            s.insert(m);
            u = m;
        }
    }
    cout << u;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На сайте куда мы скидываем решения задач что нам задали выдало ту же ошибку - "Превышение лимита памяти", я могу скинуть ссылку на задачу, если нужно

Comment: Оффтоп: а что там сайт сам и компилит тут же? и оценку сам ставит ? Это какой вуз у нас такой продвинутый? :)

Comment: в ЮУрГУ на кафедре ммикт есть сайт [ссылка](https://ipc.susu.ru/), там и задач олимпиадных очень много и при отправке он выводит не оценку, а ошибку, если таковая имеется. Например ошибка времени исполнения, просто ошибка в тестах проверки и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
map<string, int> m;
while (cin >> s && s != "#")
{
    if(m[s] == 2) continue;
    m[s]++;
}
for (const auto& p : m)
    if(p.second == 1) {
        cout << p.first;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: На сайте куда мы скидываем решения задач что нам задали выдало ту же ошибку - "Превышение лимита памяти", я могу скинуть ссылку на задачу, если нужно

Comment: Это потому что вы со своим кодом запутали. В задаче говорится о файле, а   с файлом  уже попроще

Comment: Хм, я что-то не подумал над этим, ведь можно же не хранить, а просто "ходить" по файлу

Comment: если память критична, то именно так и нужно делать